# Index vs Aggregation Pipeline for Sorting

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

I'm developing an application using MongoDB as its database, and for sorting data, I encountered an interesting argument from a colleague that index can be used instead of aggregation pipeline for getting sorted data.

I tried this and it actually works; using an index with specified field and direction does return sorted data when queried. When using aggregation pipeline, I also obtained the same result.

I have created an index with the following specification:

```
index name: batch_deleted_a_desc

num: asc
marked: asc
value: desc
```

Using aggregation pipeline:

```
> db.test.aggregate([{$match: {num:"3",marked:false}}, {$sort:{"value":-1}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d70b40ba7bebd3d7c135615"), "value" : 4, "marked" : false, "num" : "3" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d70b414a7bebd3d7c135616"), "value" : 2, "marked" : false, "num" : "3" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d70b3fea7bebd3d7c135614"), "value" : 1, "marked" : false, "num" : "3" }
```

Using index:

```
> db.test.find({num:"3",marked:false})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d70b40ba7bebd3d7c135615"), "value" : 4, "marked" : false, "num" : "3" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d70b414a7bebd3d7c135616"), "value" : 2, "marked" : false, "num" : "3" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d70b3fea7bebd3d7c135614"), "value" : 1, "marked" : false, "num" : "3" }
```

As you can see, the results are the same. But I am unsure that using index for getting sorted data is a good practice, and yet using aggregation pipeline is (sometimes) taking more effort than just creating index.

***So, which would be the best option?***

Comment: The query under the 'Using index' section does not specify a sort, is this intended? Aggregations, as well as normal queries, can use indexes to improve the performance of filtering and sorting (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes).

Comment: Yes, the query under 'Using index' section does not specify sorting to demonstrate that the index does the sorting by the index's specification.

Comment: Also, I agree that indexes can be used for improving performance, **but not to do the sorting itself**, which in this case, it does. So what should be the best option, to use index or aggregation pipeline for sorting? Thanks @AdamHarrison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the question, the better option would be the aggregation because *it explicitly specifies the sort*.

In the query example, results are being returned in order specified by the index because the query is using the index `{ num: 1, marked: 1, value: 1}`. However, nothing specified in the query will guarantee that ordering, meaning results may change at some point in the future. For example, consider the case where the index `{ num: 1, marked: 1, updated_at: 1 }` were to be created. The query planner may decide to use this index instead, which may result in results in a different order.

In the absence of a sort, a query would return results in the order of the index being used, but you should not rely upon that ordering without explicitly specifying it. Quoting the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#result-ordering):

> Unless you specify the sort() method or use the $near operator,
>   MongoDB does not guarantee the order of query results.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, it clears this argument and provides solid reason as well. Thanks a lot @AdamHarrison

Comment: Glad I could help!